# Bootstrap col-md-offset-* not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add Bootstrap offset class in my code to achieve diagonal alignment like this:

[image]

But I don't know what offset should I use. I've tried couple of offsets to achieve this but no use.Text is covering whole jumbotron.Here is my code

Html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <h2 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">Browse.</h2>
                    <h2 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">create.</h2>
                    <h2 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">share.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(img/bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.jumbotron h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
}

.jumbotron h2:first-child {
    margin: 120px 0 0;
}
```

Please guide me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your offsets be more like 2-4-6 instead of 4-4-4?

Comment: Add text and break lines in one div with 'text-align: right'

Comment: For me the 4.0.0-beta didn't work for offsets but then 4.0.0-beta.2 did work. Perhaps there was a bug there (ah, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/46503532/8479). Note that now the offset classes in bootstrap v4 look like `offset-md-4` rather than `col-md-offset-4`.

Comment: Looks like you want them to be right aligned. Using offset you are still at the mercy of browser display and zoom. Wouldn't it wiser to simply place a container div and right-align the three lines?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would not recommend utilizing the Grid system in this instance, as much as simply adding an increased padding for each `<h2>`.  That being said, the way you would achieve this using `col-*-offset-*` would be as follows:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>One</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">
                <h2>Two</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                <h2>Three</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially the first line must span the entire row (so -12).  The second line must be offset by 1 column, so you offset by 1 and give it a total width of 11 columns (11+1 = 12) and so forth.  Your offset is always enough to ensure that the total column count equals 12.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much :) @RobertC

Answer (score 190):

It works in bootstrap 4, there were some changes in documentation.We don't need prefix col-, just **offset-md-3** e.g.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-6"> Some content...
   </div>
</div>
```

Here [doc](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-offsetting-columns).

Comment: Is this still working? At the time I am unable to make the offset with and without col-*

Comment: hey, its hard to answer your question, add some code or snippet with your problem.

Comment: This solved my problem that I was working on for the last few hours. I was ready to not use the theme.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks! I can't even find it on the migrating from bootstrap 3 to 4 guide in their website...

Answer (score 25):

Changing `col-md-offset-*` to `offset-md-*` worked for me

Answer (score 10):

In bootstrap 3 the format is

```
col-md-6 col-md-offset-3
```

For the same grid in Bootstrap 4 the format is

```
col-md-6 offset-md-3
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Saw this and realized I was using bootstrap 3 and it helped me get the offset I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

Kindly use `offset-md-4` instead of `col-md-offset-4` in bootstrap 4. It's little changes adopted in bootstrap 4.

[For more info](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-offsetting-columns)

Answer (score 2):

check this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/PHwu8eLlmI)

this is wrong because bootstrap using margin-left:**%

```
.jumbotron h2:first-child {
   margin: 120px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be :

```
<h2 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Browse.</h2>
<h2 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">create.</h2>
<h2 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">share.</h2>
```

Comment: Corrected it. But still not working! Anyways, thank you! @MrGeek

Answer (score 1):

## Where's the problem

In your HTML all `h2`s have the same off-set of 4 columns, so they won't make a diagonal.

## How to fix it

A `row` has 12 columns, so we should put every `h2` in it's own `row`.
You should have something like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <h2 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Browse.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <h2 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">create.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <h2 class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">share.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

An alternative is to make every `h2` width plus offset sum 12 columns, so each one automatically wraps in a new line.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <h2 class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">Browse.</h2>
                <h2 class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">create.</h2>
                <h2 class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">share.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my answer, 'cause I realized I had misinterpreted the question. Sorry.

Comment: Hey! it's still not working.By the way thanks :)
@DanieleBarresi

Comment: You're right. Edited to fix it. Now it works. I should point out that this only makes a diagonal on screens bigger than 992px, which is the `md` size. If you need it for every screen size, replace `md` with `xs`.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 offset classes have been removed in Beta 1, but will be restored in Beta 2 -
[topic reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45652882/947668)

Answer (score 1):

For now, If you want to move a column over just 4 column units for instance, I would suggest to use just a dummy placeholder like in my example below

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">Offset 4 column</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
            //content
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <h2 class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">Browse.</h2>
                    <h2 class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">create.</h2>
                    <h2 class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">share.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with small tweak - 
we know that bootstrap works with a width of 12

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
            Keep it blank it becomes left offset
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-5">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
            Keep it blank it becomes right offset
      </div
</div>
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this, but i was in a hurry so used this trick