# Offsetting columns is not working (Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Boostrap 4(Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta) Beta and facing issues with offsetting columns.
Earlier i used to do **offset-md-*** and it was working, with BS4 Beta this is removed according to docs.
The new method mentioned in docs is using **.ml-auto** , when i try to use it with **col-md-4** it is offsetting 4 columns. What i want is custom offsetting like

```
**<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2"></div>**
```

I tried using

```
**<div class="col-md-4 ml-md-2"></div>**
```

but didn't work
Is this is bug or there is another way to do it ?

Here is official docs about offsetting 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns
[image: Bootstrap v4 Beta]

Comment: Why are you using `ml`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 `offset` classes were temporarily removed in Beta 1, but were restored in [Beta 2](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/23445).

The class names `col-{breakpoint}-offset-*` were replaced with `offset-{breakpoint}-*`

The new [auto-margins also work for offsetting columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) will move the column over as much as possible. So, it depends on how much you want to "push" the column to the right. If they're no other columns to the right of the `col-md-4` it will go all the way if to right side of the `row`. <strike>Basically `offset` was relevant for floated columns but is no longer relevant now that Bootstrap 4 is flexbox.</strike>

If you want to move the `col-md-4` over just 2 column units, the best way would be to use a **dummy/placeholder column**...

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
            ..
      </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/SqrQIOAY7

If there are other `col-md-4` to the right of the first, then `ml-auto` and `mr-auto` would work to **center both columns**...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">
            .
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mr-auto">
            .
        </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/SqrQIOAY7n

If you want to center the `col-md-4` then simply use `mx-auto` to **create equal margins on both sides**.

---

Note: specific column [**offsets will be restored as of Beta 2**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/23445)

Comment: Thanks but this blank div with col-md-2 seems like a "Hack" no?, this is what i used before posting this question. I will use your 2nd solution as i have another col-md-4 to the right, i will let you know if this solves my issue.

Comment: It may seem like a hack, but it's the only solution now that the offsets have been replaced by auto margins.

Comment: Thanks alot for your tip , your 2nd solution worked for me and i guess for time being i will use a blank div on other places till Bootstrap get something new for offsetting.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You're saying `offset` is no longer relevant now that Bootstrap 4 is flexbox, but that they will be restored? Why would they restore them if they aren't relevant?

Comment: Beta2 is out now. Has offset been restored?

Answer (score 4):

Changing

```
offset-md-2
```

to:

```
col-md-offset-2
```

Worked for me

Comment: No. This isn't working in `Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta`. as specified in question.

Answer (score 1):

`ml-md-auto` sets `margin-left: auto;` for sizes `md` and above.

You can't set that to something like `2`.

You need to do `ml-md-auto`.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap v4 Beta , you provided doc link of Alpha version. Updated my question with link of docs.

Comment: Oliver when i try to use ml-md-auto it offsets 4 columns, what i want is offsetting 2 columns but with having col-md-4

Comment: @PrashantSharma It will offset as much as it can. What you can do is set the next column to have that class as well to fix it.