# Bootstrap 4 offset not working how can I solve it?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 offset not working how can I solve it ?I have tried many times it's not behaving like the previous bootstrap please help me!my question is how can i find offset in this new version of bootstrap ?

Comment: Could you please show exactly what your error is? Your question is very vague.

Comment: there is no offset class!

Comment: If that is the issue, show that in your question.

Comment: my question is how can i find offset in this new version of bootstrap ??am i clear to you !please download the new bootstrap then try to use col-md-offset then you will understand everything !

Comment: Ok. Can you please **edit** your **question** above so that it includes more **detail** about your issue

Comment: I have edited it now help me to solve the problem please give me a proper solution !

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your error. An error message?

Comment: <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap ng Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: In your question, add that to your question

Answer (score 68):

***Updated 2018***

Column [offsets have been *restored* as of Beta 2](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/23445)

The [offset classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) are `offset-(breakpoint)-*`

---

**Original answer (Bootstrap 4 Beta 1)**

Offset, push, pull no longer exist in Bootstrap 4 beta so you must use [auto-margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mx-auto">
        I'm centered and offset 4 columns
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/gIVefoBaAm

---

**Also see**: [Offsetting columns is not working (Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650990/offsetting-columns-is-not-working-bootstrap-v4-0-0-beta/45652882)

Comment: Thank you so much i have got it !

Comment: The docs clearly use offset-md-3 and other sizes, yet it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You downvote my answer because what's stated in the docs "doesn't seem to work"?