# Bootstrap grid place div next to div in a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I want div 4 next to div 1 and below div 2 and 3 like the image below the code. How can I do that? Actual Code:

```
       <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-4 col_trainings">1</div>
             <div class="col-md-3 col_downloads">2</div>
             <div class="col-md-3 col_project">3</div>
             <div class="col-sm-6 col_contact">4</div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mx-auto class to your 4th div.

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 col_trainings">1</div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col_downloads">2</div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col_project">3</div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto col_contact">4</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

This property will set your last block on the 5th column of bootstrap ;)

Have a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680321/bootstrap-4-offset-not-working-how-can-i-solve-it). Enjoy !

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Nothing changes when I add col-offset-4.

Comment: Ok, with bootstrap 4 offset doesn't exist anymore. 
You can replace it by mx-auto
I edit my response.

Comment: Nothing changes.

Comment: What is your current bootstrap version ?

Comment: It's version 4.0.0

Comment: that weird, it's working for me with bootstrap v4.0.0
Are you sure to have'nt any style who's can overload it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for this.
"Lightweight and independent Pinterest-like cascading grid layout library" http://bricklayer.js.org