# How to create a offset in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

First of all Big apologies for my bad English.

I am using bootstrap version 4 beta version ( latest not alpha). It is good. But i'm wondering in the new version of bootstrap they removed offset class. I will thankful if someone give me the solution how can I make a offset using flexbox with any amount. I mean before I used .col-offset-2 this means offset 2 column, I want this with flexbox. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

You can use **.offset- .offset-sm- .offset-md- .offset-lg- .offset-xl-**

```
<div class="offset-2 col-8">
    test 
</div>
```

Here are some examples - http://formoid.com/articles/bootstrap-offset-example-961.html

Answer (score 10):

The offset classes have been replace by margin classes. These are prefixed `mr-` for *margin-right* and `ml-` for *margin-left*.

The [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) demonstrates the use of `ml-*-auto` (where * is the target resolution -- eg lg or md.) This is the equivalent of setting `margin-left: auto` in your CSS, which is effectively saying "push this as far left as you can." By using both `ml-*-auto` and `mr-*-auto`, you can effectively center your columns.

This is the full list of prefixes for the `auto` property:

- `ml-` margin left
- `mr-` margin right
- `mb-` margin bottom
- `mt-` margin top
- `mx-` horizontal margin (margin left + margin right)
- `my-` vertical margin (margin top + margin bottom)
- `m-` all margins

In addition to `auto`, you can specify the column widths -- `ml-lg-2`, etc.

So `col-offset-2`, which (I think) would shove the content left two spaces is equivalent to something like `ml-2` or `ml-lg-2`.

Answer (score 5):

Offset is replaced with ml-**-auto.

The below code will be 12 in sizes smaller than md, but 9 with an offset of 3 in sizes md and higher.. Because I have placed md inside ml-**-auto

```
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9 ml-md-auto">
        test
    </div>
```

See the official doc here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Also, there's also a really good answer here on how offset works in bootstrap 4
[Offsetting columns is not working (Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650990/offsetting-columns-is-not-working-bootstrap-v4-0-0-beta)

EDIT: 2018/10/25

Offset's were restored in Bootstrap 4 Beta 2. Here's an example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">.col-md-4 .offset-md-4</div>
</div>
```